# 2D - 3D video conversion in Raspberry pi

Tags: video, real-time

We have a system that we can not change. Systems output is 2D video in DisplayPort format. Video is in 1080 p resolution and 120 Hz. We need to convert this 2D video to 3D in realtime. We will be able to get 3D depth map. Now, I have to prepare a preliminary design report. So I kinda have to figure out how to convert 2D video to 3D.

And I think FPGA is not an option since minimum data rate is 1.62 Gb/s and FPGA can not handle this much data processing. So it leaves embedded linux as an option. Thus first question: Am I right so far? If not, why?

Secondly, what are my options in specific? I think of Rasberry pi and beaglebone. Second question: Are there any other options? I already designed a backlight unit, active shutter glass and synchronizer and now I need to implement 3D conversion block on an external circuit. Have can I do that? Is it so hard? Should I go with rasberry pi? And secondly, can rasperry pi handle displayport and 3D conversion?

So to summarize:

1) Can raspberry pi handle the 3D video conversion from DisplayPort?

2) How can I do 3D conversion in Raspberry pi? Can you give me any examples?

3) Could you explain the 3D conversion (with given depth map) method in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And I think FPGA is not an option since minimum data rate is 1.62 Gb/s and FPGA can not handle this much data processing.

This obviously depends on which FPGA board you are talking about and what inferfaces are built into it. I think they are considered an optimal solution to things like this, but they can get very expensive and, having fooled with one a bit, I can promise unless you can find existing designs/code for the task, the workload in terms of human labour is going to drastically dwarf doing it using a normal computer in a normal general purpose language.

I'm pointing this out because you are very wrong to believe an FPGA "can not handle this much data processing" -- again, they are an optimal solution performance wise -- but it is most likely not cost effective for you implementation wise.

> So it leaves embedded linux as an option.

Probably much more cost effective, implementation wise, however with respect to the Raspberry Pi:

> minimum data rate is 1.62 Gb/s

There is no possible way for any model of pi to come anywhere close to this level of I/O.

> Can raspberry pi handle the 3D video conversion from DisplayPort?

There's no DisplayPort connector so you'll have to use some kind of adapter and the fastest potential spot for that is USB 2.0, which going *in and out again* I would be very surprised if you could get more than 50 MB/s throughput and certainly 100 would be the absolute, very theoretical limit.

That's just in and out.  Of a 1.2 Ghz quad core ARM device.  This is like using a mid-range smartphone.  It certainly is not going to do complex processing of 1.62 Gbps of data.

The pi is not an appropriate solution.

Comment: What if I get the data the data through USB3 via adapter and buff the converted output through HDMI? Does raspberry pi support USB3?  Consider I do not use GPIO's ever. So I don't have to deal with interfaces, in this case1.2 GHz  64 bit processing would be enough for conversion + Buffering(120Hz , 1080p)? Also I see something like ' VideoCore IV 3D graphics core ' in here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-3-model-b/ Would it be helpful?

Comment: You can find all the specs for all models of pi a thousand places online, you do not have to ask me, and no they do not have USB 3.0. *Even if they did* what is a quad core 1.2 Ghz general purpose device going to do with 1.6 Gbps of data in realtime?  Nothing.  If it is lucky it could get it in and out again.